# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined when printing invoices and when creating database

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I am using odoo from eclipse. Whenever I try to create a new database i get this error. Also when I try to print invoice i am getting this error, now I am unable to print any invoices due to this. [image]

Comment: Hi dear, please download new odoo8. 0  from github.

Comment: I downloaded odoo8 from github last week all these days it was working fine, but today this problem has started

Comment: Create a DB using command line from the terminal, then after start server using 
./odoo.py --db-filter=dbname -d dbname -u all

Comment: see this link :    https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/explain-fields-property-24622                                https://github.com/odoo/odoo/issues/3469                    https://github.com/odoo/odoo/issues/3548

Comment: https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-1-of-undefined-28100